# Upgraded to 20.04 but I still have Unity desktop environment

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments

After updating Ubuntu to 20.04 but is showing Unity. Before 20.04, I had 18.04 upgraded from 16.04 but that also had same desktop environment.

[image: Unity on 20.04]

How can I switch to Ubuntu's default GNOME based desktop environment?

Comment: At the login, do you have a choice of desktops?

Answer (score 0):

You can install GNOME from official repositories with the commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome
```

Then log out of your current session, and choose GNOME when you log in to your user. That's it.